# Implementing two sigma sums in r

Tags: r

Any help on how to code this formula on R (It's a simpler version of what i am trying to do):

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a minimal reproducible examplem so the people can try and modify what you did: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

We can write something like the following. Not sure whether `N` is supposed to be the length of the vectors or an input:

```
V <- function(x, p){
  return(sum(x[seq_along(x)])*sum(p[1:min(35, length(p))]))
}

> V(1:10, 11:20)
[1] 8525
```